# Why does my game freeze when I try and display a menu?

Tags: android, andengine

I make a `MenuScene` when my Game loads, which grabs some intro text from `levelData` and displays it and a button to start playing the level. When the `MenuScene` is created and displayed in `onLoadComplete()` it's fine. However when I display it again when advancing the level (`levelData` is loaded with new data and the `MenuScene` reset) it freezes, showing the game at the point the level was beaten. The menu is not displayed at all. I'm just calling

```
loadIntro();
this.mScene.setChildScene(this.mIntroScene, false, true, true);
this.mEngine.stop();
```

to display the `MenuScene` (the same both times, it works the first time but not the second), where `loadIntro()` is

```
private void loadIntro() {
            this.mIntroScene = new MenuScene(this.mCamera);

            final TextMenuItem intro = new TextMenuItem(-1, mFont, levelData.getIntroText());
            intro.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            intro.setSize(400, 150);
            this.mIntroScene.addMenuItem(intro);

            final SpriteMenuItem startMenuItem = new SpriteMenuItem(MENU_START, this.mMenuStartTextureRegion);
            startMenuItem.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            this.mIntroScene.addMenuItem(startMenuItem);

            this.mIntroScene.buildAnimations();
            this.mIntroScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
            this.mIntroScene.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run through the code with a debugger?  Do you know where the problem is?  My guess is that something is not be initialised properly.

Comment: Is it possible to use a separate thread for the game action?  I'm wondering if the menu being activated is consuming the current thread (this is only a guess).

Comment: @Randolf rewriting into a separate thread fixed it, write up an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible to use a separate thread for the game action?  I'm wondering if the menu being activated is consuming the current thread (this is a guess based on my experience in programming applications in Java that use menus).

I suspect that what's going on is that you have one main thread, and that by activating the menu your code is temporarily halted while the user decides what to do with the menu.